# What is the inverse of $f(x )= x \operatorname e^{|x|}$?

Tags: inverse

The function $$f(x )= x  \operatorname e^{|x|} $$has an interesting semi-sigmoid shape. However, it is somehow a "horizontal" sigmoid. I would like to know the function of the vertical equivalent. So what is the inverse of this function?

Comment: The Wikipedia plot summary for the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) may be relevant here.

Comment: Notice that $f(x)> 0$ for $x>0$—and it is a odd function—so it suffices to consider the inverse of the function $(0, \infty) \to (0, \infty)$

Comment: Thanks for your input so far. @GoodBoy; yes, it should suffice to find the inverse of ()=e()

Comment: As written by Brian Rung, the function you are looking for is called Lambert W function. It is a special function. You can not express it with other simpler functions, but you can find plot and properties on Wikipedia.

Comment: Thank you all! Now that I have learned that the function has a name a whole new world has opened up for me :-). I have already found a bunch om interesting articles dealing with the function. Good to know that there is no inverse of it (the effort I put in trying to find one almost drove me crazy...). Seems as if it is a quite an established function; albeit not in my area (statistical models of psychological phenomena). I can already see som nice applications of the function in my area :-)

Comment: So the inverse of ()=()exp(x) is called the "Lambert W"-function. Then; what is the original function called? I suppose there is a better name than just "the inverse of Lambert W". If not; can anyone come up with a better name than "the xexpabs-function"?

Comment: According to Goerg a possible application of the (x)exp(x)-function might be when we want to "Gaussianize" skewed distributions of data in order to be "allowed" to analyze the distributions  with parametric statistical  tests. See for example  datahttps://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4562338/
I have a hunch that the (x)exp(x)-function will do a better job than the logit-function when we want to ”Gaussianize” proportion data (or probabities or percentages) . However, whether that is true remains to be seen… I will explore it further.